# in tcl, how to edit string in the open file?

Tags: tcl

let's say that I have opened a file using:

`set in [open "test.txt" r]`

I'm intend to revise some string in the certain line, like:

`style="fill:#ff00ff;fill-opacity:1"`
and this line number is: 20469

And I want to revise the value `ff00ff` to other string value like `ff0000`.

What are the proper ways to do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: When a file is opened with r mode (read-only), you cannot make any modifications to the file while it is open You either have to read the entire file once, close the file, then overwrite the whole file with the modified information, or you use the [fileutil](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/fileutil/fileutil.html#10) module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to open the file in read-write mode; the `r+` mode is probably suitable.

In most cases with files up to a reasonable number of megabytes long, you can `read` the whole file into a string, process that with a command like `regsub` to perform the change in memory, and then write the whole thing back after `seek`ing to the start of the file. Since you're not changing the size of the file, this will work well. (Shortening the file requires explicit truncation.)

```
set f [open "test.txt" r+]
set data [read $f]
regsub {(style="fill:#)ff00ff(;fill-opacity:1)"} $data {\1ff0000\2} data
seek $f 0
puts -nonewline $f $data
# If you need it, add this here by uncommenting:
#chan truncate $f
close $f
```

There are other ways to do the replacement; the choice depends on the details of what you're doing.

Comment: If I want to use 'regsub {(style="fill:#)ff00ff(;fill-opacity:1)"} $data {\1$color\2} data' and I have 'set color "ff0000"', how could I write the code? Thanks!